How to keep UIView height consistent when UILabel text varies between 1 and 3 lines?
I have a view structure implemented in Swift using UIKit where a UIView contains a UILabel. The UILabel can have text with 1 line at minimum and up to 3 lines at maximum. I want to ensure that the UIView’s height remains consistent even when the UILabel has only 1 line of text.
Here are the details:
The UIView has 12-point constraints on all edges (top, leading, bottom, and trailing) to the UILabel.
The UILabel should grow to accommodate up to 3 lines, but the UIView should remain the same height even if the text has only 1 line.
How can I add a constraint to the UIView to ensure its height remains the same regardless of whether the UILabel has 1 line or up to 3 lines of text?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

At this point, my code is something like below.
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create the parent view (container for the UILabel)
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(containerView)

        // Create the UILabel
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 3 // Max number of lines
        label.text = "This is a sample text for UILabel"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)

        containerView.addSubview(label)

        // Add constraints for the containerView (assuming it has 12 points padding to the edges)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100)
        ])

        // Add constraints for the UILabel within the containerView
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12)
        ])
    }
}


You need to give containerView a fixed height. For example:         containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100). Keep the label constrains the same.  So the label's height is determined by the container's fixed height and the padding you set

You need subclass UILabel and in intrinsicContentSize return font.lineHeight. * numberOfLines and call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize in font and numberOfLines setters

You can provide a label that already is filled up with 3 lines, maybe a mock text such as lorem ipsum dolor.... And then adding edge constraints for this label as a placeholder. These steps could be:
let placeholder = UILabe()
placeholder.numberOfLines = 3
placeholder.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor..." //<- a long text here
placeholder.alpha = 0 //<- hide the placeholder

container.addSubView(placeholder)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    //Placeholder's constraints to fill the edge of container with inset = 12
])

//Real content here
let contentLabel = UILabel()
container.addSubView(contentLabel)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    contentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: placeholder.leadingAnchor),
    contentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: placeholder.trailingAnchor),
    contentLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: placeholder.bottomAnchor),
    contentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: placeholder.topAnchor)
])

Output


To calculate the height:

For fixed value you can set a UILabel with three lines and using UI debugging or on a button tap you can get the height.

For dynamically calculating height use the following function with matching label properties
func calculateLabelHeight(fontSize: CGFloat, lines: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
 // Get single line height
 let label = UILabel()
 label.text = "Text"
 label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
 label.sizeToFit()

 return label.frame.height * lines
}



After getting the height include the top and bottom constants and add constraint
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 85)

After setting height you will get a view like this 
If you want to align label text at top, change the label bottom constraint to label.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12)
Now the view will look like 
If you want to add background color for label it will only show background along the text.
To add the full background color with 12 spacing while keeping the text at top, need to add an extra container for label
    let labelContainer = UIView()
    labelContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    labelContainer.backgroundColor = .white
    containerView.addSubview(labelContainer)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        labelContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
        labelContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
        labelContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 12),
        labelContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12)
    ])
    
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 3 // Max number of lines
    label.text = "This is a sample text for UILabel mg"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    labelContainer.addSubview(label)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainer.leadingAnchor),
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainer.trailingAnchor),
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainer.topAnchor),
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: labelContainer.bottomAnchor)
    ])

Now background color can be added separately for labelContainer and label 

You cannot do this with constraints only...
Assuming you want the text to be "top-aligned," probably the most straightforward way to accomplish your goal:

add a label with two line-feeds to make it 3 lines tall
add a label for the "actual" text
constrain the "three-line" label to the container with 12-points on all 4 sides
constrain the Top / Leading / Trailing (but not Bottom) of the "actual" label to the three-line label

It will look like this in Debug View Hierarchy ("actual" label is cyan, "three-line" label is yellow, with text for clarification):

When "actual" label has only one-line worth of text:

with a bit more text:

with too much text, so it will be truncated at 3 lines:

Your example code, modified:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Create the parent view (container for the UILabel)
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        
        // Create the UILabel
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 3 // Max number of lines
        label.text = "This is a sample text for UILabel"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        
        containerView.addSubview(label)

        // Create the "sizing" UILabel
        let threeLineLabel = UILabel()
        threeLineLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        threeLineLabel.numberOfLines = 3 // Max number of lines
        // this will give us 3 empty lines
        threeLineLabel.text = "\n\n"
        
        // make sure we're using the same font
        threeLineLabel.font = label.font
        
        containerView.addSubview(threeLineLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(label)

        // Add constraints for the containerView (assuming it has 12 points padding to the edges)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100)
        ])
        
        // Add constraints for the UILabel within the containerView
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            threeLineLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            threeLineLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            threeLineLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            threeLineLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12),
            
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: threeLineLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: threeLineLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: threeLineLabel.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            // don't constrain the bottom
            
        ])
        
        // if we want a background color for the full 3-line-height frame
        threeLineLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }
    
}


If that seems like a workable solution for your needs, you'd probably want to wrap that into a UIView subclass, and implement either public vars or funds to set the various properties.

A solution which works with Dynamic Type is below:
You can demo this in Preview. In order to test with Dynamic Type, you'd better use a device or the simulator.
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

final class MyLabelView: UIView {
    let hStack: UIStackView
    let labelView: UILabel
    let paddingX: CGFloat = 12.0
    let paddingY: CGFloat = 12.0
    let numberOfLines = 3
    
    private var hStackHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    var text: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.update()
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    init() {
        labelView = UILabel()
        hStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [labelView])
        super.init(frame: .zero) // frame will be computed
        self.setUp()
    }
    
    convenience init(text: String) {
        self.init()
        self.text = text
    }
    
    private func setUp() {
        hStack.axis = .horizontal
        hStack.alignment = .center
        hStack.distribution = .fill
        
        labelView.numberOfLines = numberOfLines
        labelView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        labelView.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true

        hStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hStackHeightAnchor = hStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 8.0)

        #if DEBUG
        labelView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        labelView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        hStack.layer.borderWidth = 1
        hStack.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        // self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        // self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        #endif
        
        
        self.addSubview(hStack)
        self.hStack.addSubview(labelView)
                
        // Note:
        // To detect changes to dynamic font size, we need to
        // override the traitCollectionDidChange(_:) method in
        // your view or view controller, and check for changes
        // to the content size category trait. Then, call
        // setNeedsUpdateConstraints() for self.
        // Alternatively, we can also observe didChangeNotification
        // and update the font when the notification arrives:
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification,
            object: nil,
            queue: OperationQueue.main
        ) { _ in
            print("UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification")
            self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        }
    }
    
    private func update() {
        self.labelView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text)
    }
    
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        hStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: paddingY).isActive = true
        hStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: paddingX).isActive = true
        hStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -paddingX).isActive = true
    }
    
    override func updateConstraints() {
        // guess the required height for numberOfLines lines:
        let heightThatFits = CGFloat(numberOfLines) * (labelView.font.lineHeight + 2)
        print("labelView heightThatFits: \(heightThatFits)")
        hStackHeightAnchor?.constant = heightThatFits
        hStackHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
        super.updateConstraints()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.labelView.sizeToFit()
        print("labelView.sizeToFit: \(self.labelView.frame.size)")
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}

// MARK: - Preview

struct MySwiftUILabelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let text: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MyLabelView {
        MyLabelView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MyLabelView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}


#Preview {
    MySwiftUILabelView(text: "Hello World!")
}

#Preview {
    MySwiftUILabelView(text: "Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! ")
}

Caveat:
Definitely convoluted. Say Hi to UIKit ;)
Does also demo nicely why we use SwiftUI nowadays ;)
